# Graylog: how to search for custom properties

Tags: graylog2

I would like to know how can I search for log messages with a custom properties containing a field named “Main Status” and value “Starting Process”…

how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the assumption that the field is "Main_Status" or "MainStatus". Otherwise you may need to encode it "Main&20%Status", but I'd expect that to be problematic.

If that's acceptable then a query with the field and value would be something like `Main_Status:Starting Process*`.

You could also verify that the the field exists with something like `Main_Status:Starting Process* AND _exists_:Main_Status`.